# A5/1 security algorithm 3

Tags: c, security

In the following link, we have a pedagogical implementation of the A5/1 algorithm. I know how it works but I can't understand what the `bit parity(word x)` function is for? I know what it is, but just tell me how it works.

```
typedef unsigned long word;
typedef word bit;

/* Calculate the parity of a 32-bit word, i.e. the sum of its bits modulo 2 */
bit parity(word x) {
    x ^= x>>16;
    x ^= x>>8;
    x ^= x>>4;
    x ^= x>>2;
    x ^= x>>1;
    return x&1;
}
```

Algorithm link: 
http://scard.org/gsm/a51.html

Comment: If you want people to look at your code, you'll need to provide it on this site. If it's too long, take a look at [this help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from making some probably unwarranted assumptions about type sizes (these days, `unsigned long` is often 64-bit, not 32-bit), it isn't very hard code.

Given that `x` is a 32-bit value, then:

- `x ^= x >> 16;` xors the top 16 bits of `x` with the bottom 16 bits.  The bottom 16 bits each gives the parity of a pair of bits in the original 32-bit word.

This process repeats for the bottom 8 bits, then 4, then 2, then 1 bits, so that in the end, the least significant bit is the parity of the original 32-bit value.

If `unsigned long` is a 64-bit value, the code still produces the parity of the less significant 32-bits of the input value.